# error expected a declaration c ++

Tags: c++, function

UPDATE 2: well I fixed it, turns out it was a simple matter of a semi column getting in where it didn't belong, was looking in completely the wrong place.

UPDATE:removing some comments fixed the cin cout errors, now the only errors are expected a declaration on the opening and closing brackets and one has appeared on the else statement.

the Error "expected a declaration" appears in the function playeroneturn on the opening and closing {} aswell as the closing } of the if statement in the function, also in the if statement the cin and cout both give the error "this declaraton has no storage class or type specifier"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "ctime"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "string"

//prototype function declaration from stackoverflow.com/questions/2575153/must-declare-function-prototype-in-c
int help(int menu);
int start(int menu);
int oneplaymode();
int playeroneturn();
int playertwoturn();

//function start is called to display the games menu screen
int start(int menu)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;
    cout << "#########################################################################" << endl;
    cout << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t    PIGS\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t1. 1 Player\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t2. 2 Player\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t3. help\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl<< "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl<< "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl<< "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl<< "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl<< "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl;
    cout << "#########################################################################" << endl;
    cout << "enter number for your selection: ";
    cin >> menu;
    if(menu == 1)
    {
        cout << "single-player not yet implemented" << endl;

    }
    else if(menu == 2)
    {
    int twoplayermode();
    }
    else if(menu == 3)
    {
    help(menu);
    }
    else
    {
    cout << "Error: Please choose a valid option" << endl;

    start(menu); 

    }
return(menu);
}

int help(int menu)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;    
    cout << "#########################################################################" << endl;
    cout << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t HELP\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#  The objective of pigs is to be the first to score 100.\t\t#" << endl << "#  Each turn you must roll a die then pass or roll again.\t\t#" << endl << "#  You must then choose to ROLL again or END your turn.\t\t\t#" << endl << "#  At the end of your turn your total is added to your score.\t\t#" << endl << "#  However if you roll a 1 your turn ends and you score 0.\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl << "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl<< "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl<< "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl<< "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl<< "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl<< "#\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#" << endl;
    cout << "#########################################################################" << endl;
    system("pause");
    start(menu);
    return 0;
}

int playeroneturn(int p1score);
{
    using namespace std;
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;
    using std::srand;
    using std::rand;
    using std::time;
    using std::string;
    srand((unsigned int)time(0)); 
    int roll = 0;
    int p1score = 0;
    string reroll = "roll";
    while(reroll == "roll") 
    {
        roll = 1 + (rand() % 6);
            if(roll > 1)
            {
                p1score = p1score+roll;
                // using " in a string msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5.aspx
                cout << "You rolled a " << roll << endl << "Type roll to roll again or end to end your turn."; // error on cout this declaraton has no storage class or type specifier and error on first << expected a ;
                cin >>  reroll; 
            }
            else 
            { 
                cout >> "Bad luck! you rolled a 1, your turn is over and you score nothing!"
                p1score = 0; 
                reroll = end;
            }
    }
    return p1score; 
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of mistakes - `continue` is a reserved word; you cannot mix `>>` and `<<` in `cout`, use only `<<`; You cannot have statements like `1 + (rand() % 6); = roll` - what is this supposed to do? What is before the first `{`, etc.

Comment: what are the function name, and parameters?

Comment: I, aside from all the others already pointed out, don't see where you make it possible to use `string` instead of `std::string`.

Answer (score 8):

I see several issues (from my comment):

- you cannot have statements like `1 + (rand() % 6); = roll`. What is this supposed to do? If you want `roll` to be `1 + (rand() % 6);`, write it `roll = 1 + (rand() % 6);`
- you cannot use `continue` as variable, it's reserved keyword
- you cannot mix `>>` and `<<` when using `cout`. Use only `<<`.
- `p1score` is not initialized (it's not compiler's error, but still - you use it (in the body of the `if-statement`, where the first condition (`if(roll > 1)`) is true) without being initialized, so you'll get garbage value
- have you included `#include <string>`?
- you don't have `using std::string` and if you don't have `using namespace std;`, you'll have a compiler error for this, too.
- waiting for an answer - what is before the first `{`.

---

**EDIT:** Looking at you edit, you need to do some other changes:

- first, the definition of `playeroneturn` is wrong: `int playeroneturn(int p1score); { ... }` <- remove `;` before the function's body
- note, that in `playeroneturn`, `int p1score = 0;` shadows the parameter of the function, it has the same name
- again in `playeroneturn` - `cout` *must* be used with `<<`, not with `>>`
- a ';' must be added after the wrong `cout` (from the previous point)
- in `playeroneturn` (again), `reroll = end;` is bad - what is this `end`, it's not defined nowhere.

Comment: ok I have included the current code completely including all code prior to the first { as requested in the post, I have had some success following your advice the expected declaration error now only occurs on the opening and closing {} of the function and the } of the if statement. a new error has appeared inside the if statement on both the cin and cout statement "this declaraton has no storage class or type specifier" also the >> and << beside those statements now expect a ; however i would hazard a guess that fixing the first issue will also solve the latter.

Comment: also i fee like a complete dunce for making so many mistakes, i guess that's why i was having so much trouble finding them, i was only looking for one.

Answer (score 3):

`continue` is a keyword and may not be used as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(continue == "roll")
{
    1 + (rand() % 6); = roll //<--- what is this? no ; and no l value
        if(roll > 1)
```

where is semicolon and lvalue?

Answer (score 0):

continue is a [keyword / reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). and hence it should not be used as a variable name or other literal specification.For feeling the difference just rename the variable 'continue' to 'continue1' and see the error go. Hope this will help.